# TypeError: string is null

Tags: jquery

I am getting type error string is null,

i am checking string like this:

```
if (typeof s != 'undefined' || s.length){
        var j = JSON.stringify(
            s.split(',').reduce(function(m,v) {
               var t = v.split(':');
               m[t[0]] = t[1];
               return m;
            }, {})
         );
}
```

But still it shows type error,
tell me how to not run this function on `null` ?

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: because `s` is null :-), how to check if `s` is not equal to `null

Comment: if (s) should be good enough to check that it's not null.

Comment: you tryed with this syntax `typeof(s) !== 'undefined'`?

Comment: @HanletEscaño, error was gone. Please post your comment as answer so that I can select it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all `null` and `undefined` are two distinct values, so for the short circuiting to work you need to test both undefined and null you wouldn't need the typeof function for that you could simply do

```
if(s != undefined && s != null && s.length)
```

that changes the logic in your code because you are testing with `||` but that will always fail in your case (it will only be used if the type of s is undefined)

however since both null and undefined are falsy values. That is used as a boolean expression they both evaluate to false you can simply do

```
if(s && s.length){
}
```

There's quite a few falsy values in JS

- null
- undefined
- "" //empty string
- 0
- false

The last one is the only truely false value so if you do `value === false` only the last of those five will evaluate to true where as all of them will evaluate to false in a condition

Any string that has a length is also a truthy value there's one somewhat surprising value that evaluates to true which is `"false"` and since all strings with a length > 0 will evaluate to true the only way the above if will fail is if there's no length property. That's is if it's not a string (or an array or any other type with a length property).

So you could either remove the test of length altogether

```
if(s){
}
```

or make it explicit that you are testing for a string

```
if(s && typeof s === "string"){
}
```

Comment: `s != null` will it work? cause I heard that `null` is not equal to anything not even null

Comment: @user007 Just try it in your console in your browser write `null != null`that will answerthe question (the answer is yes it will work)
null semantics vary from language to language E.g. in SQL your assumption would be correct in JS,Java,c++ or C# your assumption is not correct. SQL is more true to the original null semantics where null is "I don't know the value" and logically if you compare too things but you don't knwo what they are the it follows that you don't know if they are equal or not (I.e. the result would be null) that's the original semantics but not the semantics in JS

Answer (score 1):

To check for null string you should probably try this:

```
if(s)
{}
```

as far as for empty string, checking the length the way you are should be fine and probably faster than `===` or `==`.

Comment: will it check for undefined ??

Comment: Undefined means it has not been set a value. If you initialize it you should not have to check for it, but I guess also checking for it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @HanletEscaño your comment is not entirely accurate since it's possible to assign undefined and undefined is a value (that can actually be redefined!) so even though you have assigned to the variable you are not guaranteed that the value is not undefined